# Turbodbc very slow on batch inserts

Tags: database, unixodbc, turbodbc

I am investigating whether Turbodbc can solve a problem for us when it come to massive amounts of DB inserts. We are talking millions of batch inserts. At the moment, it is a lot slower than any other solutions I have tried, for instance mongodb inserts, and pandas's to_sql function. I am not sure if I am missing a setting or something specific. Does anyone have experience with Turbodbc and maybe experienced the same issue?

- I have tried on a mac, as well as dockerised debian(buster) environment.
- I have tried executemanycolumns, as well as executemanywith a sql query, both slow.
- I have installed unixodbc
- For debian I am using these MySQL ODBC drivers

  https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19-linux-debian10-x86-64bit.tar.gz

The gist of the code is as follows

```
import turbodbc

connection = turbodbc.connect('astcdr', turbodb_options=options)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True

// *** Measuring duration of operation
// Loading a big CSV
// *** Measuring duration of operation
// Mutate some data
// *** Measuring duration of operation
// Build the sql
// *** Measuring duration of operation
....

// Execute
cursor.executemany(sql, dataArray) <- this operation takes long
// *** Measuring duration of operation
```

My odbc.ini file looks as follow

```
[astcdr]
Description=MySQL connection to database
Driver=MySQL
Database=test
Server=mysql_container
User=test
Password=test
Port=3306
```

My odbcinst.ini looks as follow

```
[ODBC Drivers]
MySQL ODBC 8.0=Installed

[MySQL]
Driver=/var/www/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19-linux-debian10-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8w.so
UsageCount=2
```

I pip install the following, of which pybind11 fails during docker build, but it is installed when I mount the container.

```
pybind11
pandas
numpy
pyarrow
pytest
pytest-cov
mock
six
turbodbc
```

Since the result is the same on my mac, and in a dockerised env, I either made the same mistake twice in setting it up, or Turbodbc just doesn't work the way I think it does. Deos anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you should be aware of:

1. You should try another setting of `parameter_sets_to_buffer` as described in https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/advanced_usage.html. Increasing this may increase the throughput.
2. Don't compare the performance between different database. MongoDB and MySQL have different features/performance characteristics and thus INSERT performance also varies greatly. Thus it is bad to compare turbodbc+MySQL to it. I'm not aware of the MySQL OBDC driver performance but as there is a native mysql connector, this might be better than the ODBC driver which can be really slow sometimes and thus `turbodbc` won't help you. `turbodbc` will bring you speedups in comparison to `pyodbc` but requires that the ODBC driver itself is already efficient.